# Laravel: How to optimize multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-optimization, laravel-5.3

The queries on HomeController file slows down the site.  It takes 20 seconds for the page to load fully. (Page size is 3.9 Mb only, and CPU load goes up to 80% every time when i load the page).  I am told to use Query Builder which is faster than Elequant and join queries to send them as one query.  I find this too difficult. Where can i see some examples for this ?

HomeController

```
public function index()
{
    $sliders = Post::where('post_type','slider')
        ->with('FeaturedImage','PostField')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(4)
        ->get();

    $page1 = Post::where([
        ['post_type','=','custom_page'],
        ['slug','=','page1'],
    ])
        ->with('FeaturedImage','PostField')
        ->latest()
        ->first();


    $page2 = Post::where([
        ['post_type','=','custom_page'],
        ['slug','=','page2'],
    ])
        ->with('FeaturedImage','PostField')
        ->latest()
        ->first();


    $page3 = Post::where([
        ['post_type','=','custom_page'],
        ['slug','=','page-3'],
    ])
        ->with('FeaturedImage','PostField')
        ->latest()
        ->first();


    $compacts = array(
        'sliders',
        'page1',
        'page2',
        'page3',
    );
    return view('site.home')->with(compact($compacts));
}
```

edit:
Post Migration

```
public function up()
{
    // Create table for storing roles
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('author_id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('excerpt')->nullable();
        $table->text('body')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();//unique()
        $table->string('post_type')->default('post');
        $table->enum('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT', 'PENDING'])->default('DRAFT');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: _Where can i see some examples for this ?_ have you tried google? the laravel documentation?

Comment: you are basically executing a query 3 time for no reason

Comment: How join this queries as one query?

Comment: Can you show your migration for your posts table?

Comment: @patricus yes, i updated

Comment: 3.9MB is _huge_; have pity on someone far away with a slow connection; that could take minutes _just for the network_!

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL, and the table definitions.  From that, we can suggest better indexes, etc, to cut back significantly on the "80% CPU Load".

Answer (score 2):

You're running four queries against the posts table, and none of them are using indexes. This means four full table scans of the posts table. Additionally, you're sorting on an non-indexed field. This can cause performance issues as well.

You need an index on `post_type` and on `slug` for your query conditions. You can either create two individual indexes, or one composite index. It depends on your application needs.

```
$table->string('slug')->nullable()->index();
$table->string('post_type')->default('post')->index();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do something like this to get all pages, and then split the pages using the collection [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby) function

```
Post::where('post_type','=','custom_page')
->whereIn('slug',['page1','page2','page-3'])
->whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM post GROUP BY slug)')
->with('FeaturedImage','PostField')
->get()
->groupBy('slug');
```